# How to add custom property to grails Projections

Tags: grails, hibernate-criteria

I need additional value in list with grails criteria query

```
class A{
        String name
        String address
        }

        def list=A.createCriteria.list{
          projections{
           property("name","name");
           property("additionalPropertyValue;","additionalProperty");
          // this value does not exist in domain class, but I need in list
          }
        }
    Result should have additionalPropertyValue
```

Comment: could you explain more? what is that property and where does it come from? What exactly do you want there?

Comment: yes, i want to have custom property along with name, and the value of that property is returned by some other function, for example: i need name value in uppercase also, so i want to add property "uppercase" and whose value is name.toUpperCase();

Answer (score -1):

You can add a custom property by doing it this way:

```
def list = A.createCriteria.list{
               projections{
                   property("name","name")
               }
           }

list.each {
   it["additionalProperty"] = additionalPropertyValue
}
```